# Does return an address ensures non-NULL return value?

Tags: c++, c, return, return-type

In a function if I am returning an address of some primitive type of object. Can I be assured that it will never be a `NULL` value?

Do I need to check for `NULL` with a statement like

```
if (r_value) { //do something }  
else { //ERROR }
```

?

Comment: Lot of answers that assume architectures...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The address of an object will never be null.

Be careful you're not returning a pointer to a non-static local variable. That will be destroyed when the function returns, so the pointer will be invalid; but it won't be null, and there'll be no way to tell that it's no longer valid.

In C++, I'd return a reference rather than a pointer to make it clear that it won't be null. That's not an option in C of course; I don't know which of the two tagged languages you're asking about.

Answer (score 4):

The address of an existing object is guaranteed to be not NULL. So if you use such an address there is no point for NULL checking.

Answer (score 1):

Address of an object can never be null.
So you are not required to check whether the returned value is NULL.

But be sure that you are returning address of such a variable which will not go out of scope when the called function returns.

What I mean is if you return address of any object which has got memory on the stack, after returning from the function its stack frame will be popped out and hence the returned address will no longer point to the desired/valid location. This may cause runtime error in your program.

So make sure that you are not returning address of a non-static local variable or of a variable which has register storage class.

If the called function is not maintained by you and if there are chances of it getting changed in future then as a general coding practice and to avoid future hastles you can check the return value against NULL, otherwise there is no need to check returned value against NULL according to me.